# How printf works without modifiers?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char string[]="Programming Language";

    printf(string);

    printf("\n%s",string);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

> Programming Language
>    Programming Language

Why is the output same?

Comment: The output would be different if there were a `'%'` symbol in the `string` (awful variable name, that).

Comment: You should never call printf without controlling the format. If a user input has '%' in it, you will have an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `printf` parses the format string it prints the characters that are not format specifiers as they are.

So when it parses `"Programming Language"` it just echoes each character.

Answer (score 3):

The first printf statement is the same as:

```
printf("Programming Language");
```

and your second printf statement is just the same:
(Because the 'placeholder' gets replaced with the variable, + a new line at the start)

```
printf("\nProgramming Language");
```

So that's why it is the same output

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same. The second one includes a new line that is not included in the first one.

If you remove the newline, they will be the same because:

1. The first version simply prints the contents of `string`.
2. The second version uses `%s`, which is replaced with the contents of `string`.

Either way, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of printf could contains plain text besides modifiers. So basically it equals. %s is useful when you want to include some string inside of other e.g.:

```
printf ("One Two %s Four Five (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)", "Three", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Using %s modifier standalone quite meaningless. Just one thing you should remember - in the case you are not using %s modifier and pass string as a first parameter you should quote % symbol. E.g.:

```
printf ("I am 100%% sure that it would works!");
```

So basically instead just single % sign you need to use double % ( %% ). Even in the case you pass it as a variable:

```
char s [] = "50%% complete";
printf (s);
```

Hope it makes sence!